# Rust compilation errors on installaton of libcst on alpine python

Tags: python-3.x, rust, alpine-linux, libcst

trying to install python modules on alpine linux using 3.7.9 image of alpine-python

Not able to find any solution on how to get the below issues resolved, any assistance would help a lot.

```
          error[E0658]: or-patterns syntax is experimental
6908         --> libcst/src/tokenizer/core/mod.rs:944:25
6909          |
6910      944 | /                         '\n'
6911      945 | |                         | '\\'
6912      946 | |                         | '\''
6913      947 | |                         | '"'
6914      ...   |
6915      958 | |                         | 'u'
6916      959 | |                         | 'U',
6917          | |_____________________________^
6918          |
6919          = note: see issue #54883 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54883> for more information
6920      
6921      error[E0658]: or-patterns syntax is experimental
6922         --> libcst/src/tokenizer/core/mod.rs:976:33
6923          |
6924      976 |                     if let Some('"' | '\'') = self.text_pos.peek() {
6925          |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^
6926          |
6927          = note: see issue #54883 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54883> for more information
6928      
6929      error[E0658]: or-patterns syntax is experimental
6930          --> libcst/src/parser/grammar.rs:3203:14
6931           |
6932      3203 |         e @ (Expression::Integer(_) | Expression::Float(_)) => Ok(e),
6933           |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
6934           |
6935           = note: see issue #54883 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54883> for more information
6936      
6937      error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'split_inclusive'
6938        --> libcst/src/tokenizer/whitespace_parser.rs:84:26
6939         |
6940      84 |             lines: input.split_inclusive(default_newline).collect(),
6941         |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
6942         |
6943         = note: see issue #72360 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/72360> for more information
6944      
6945      error: aborting due to 4 previous errors
6946      
6947      For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0658`.
6948      error: could not compile `libcst`.
6949      
6950      Caused by:
6953      error: `cargo rustc --lib --message-format=json-render-diagnostics --manifest-path native/libcst/Cargo.toml --release -v --features pyo3/extension-module -- --crate-type cdylib` failed with code 101
6954      [end of output]
6955  
6956  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
6957  ERROR: Failed building wheel for libcst
```

Answer (score 0):

“use of unstable library feature” and “syntax is experimental” indicate you are using a version of the Rust compiler older than that required for this program.

[`or_patterns` was stabilized in Rust 1.53](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/5d04957a4b4714f71d38326fc96a0b0ef6dc5800). [`split_inclusive` was stabilized in Rust 1.51](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_inclusive) (look at the version number on the right side of the method entry).

You will need to install Rust 1.53 or newer. Right now, you are using a version that is more than a year old.